# Writing and reading files, using loops, and analyzing data

Tags: java

Im having a little trouble finishing my program.  Here is what Ive got and the instructions.  Create a file that holds 500 random numbers ranging from 0 - 1000, using a for loop to write the numbers into the file. Then 1. Find the smallest value  2. Find the largest value  3. Find the average  and 4. determine how many time consecutive numbers came up. Im having issues with creating the random number file and step 4. Thanks in advance!

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter prw = new PrintWriter("results.txt");
    File numfile = new File("randomdata.txt");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(numfile);
    int num, largest, smallest, sum = 0, count = 0;
    int programnumber = 6;
    header (prw, programnumber );
    double average = 0;

    Random gen = new Random();
    System.out.println("From gen: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        System.out.print(gen.nextInt(500) + "");
            num = gen.nextInt(500);
            System.out.println(num);
            sum = sum + num;
            count++;
            average = (double) sum / count;
    }


    while (infile.hasNext()){
        num = infile.nextInt();
        largest = infile.nextInt();
        smallest = infile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(num);
        if (num < largest){
            largest = num;
        }
        if (num > smallest){
            smallest = num;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest is: " + largest);
        prw.println("The largest is: " + largest);
        System.out.println("The smallest is: " + smallest);
        prw.println("The smallest is: " + smallest);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        prw.println("The average is: " + average);


    }
    prw.close();
}
```

Comment: So, what is the issue?

Comment: I am not able to create the file with the random numbers, and I cant figure out how to do step 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I am not able to create the file with the random numbers**

You are trying to open a non-existing file:

```
File numfile = new File("randomdata.txt");
Scanner infile = new Scanner(numfile);
```

The `Scanner` constructor tries to open the file, but it does not exist yet, so it throws a `FileNotFoundException`. You do not need the `Scanner` yet, since you first want to create that file. Use a `FileWriter` instead:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("randomdata.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    num = gen.nextInt(500);
    fw.write(num + "\n");
}
fw.close();
```

You also might need to check the `for`-loop - it generates 1000 numbers in the range 0..500, not vice versa.

Then, you need to redesign your `while`-loop:

- remove the line which reads largest/smallest from the data file. That needs to be calculated, not read from the data file.
- Move the printing of the result outside the loop - you do not need to print this with each loop iteration
- Initialize `largest` and `smallest` with reasonable values
- Move the calculation of the average from your `for`-loop inside the `while`-loop

With that, you should have a working program, where you can check whether the result is what you expected.

> **determine how many time consecutive numbers came up**

Think about how you could solve it - you want to know whether the currently read number equals the previously read number + 1. So, you need to track the previously read number in your `while`-loop, similar to what you did with `largest` and `smallest`. Beware of the first loop iteration, where no previous number exists yet.

BTW: I intentionally did not give a complete answer in code ;)

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate that, I wouldn't be able to learn that way.

Answer (score 0):

First, we aint here to do your homework ;-)

second, write first up what you want.

for example:

- create file
- write random numbers to file (0-1000) (is it allowed to have a number twice?)
- close/save the file
- open the file
- read the file
- find highest number
- find lowest number
- calc average
- count highest consecutive values

Translate that to logic you understand before trying it in java.

step 4: how would you count amount of consecutive numbers on paper?
f.e. 
 - every time a new number is one higher then the number before, increase the temp  variable. 
 - every time it is not ( new value > old value ) compare the temp variable with  highest consecutive variable and save the highest one. reset the temp variable aftewards

This would result in:

```
int largestConsecutive = 0;
int largestConsecutiveTemp=0;
int previewValue =9999;
// loop through the lines of the file, each Next elements represents one number.
// Use this loop to calc the result values, not to print out on every new number
while (infile.hasNext()){
        ... 
        if(num > previewValue){
           //do something
        } else {
           //do something
        }
        ...
}
```

The while loop is kinda wrong too on finding the smallest/largest numbers:

```
while (infile.hasNext()){
        num = infile.nextInt();
        largest = infile.nextInt();
        smallest = infile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(num);
        if (num < largest){
            largest = num;
        }
        if (num > smallest){
            smallest = num;
        }
        System.out.println("The largest is: " + largest);
        prw.println("The largest is: " + largest);
        System.out.println("The smallest is: " + smallest);
        prw.println("The smallest is: " + smallest);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        prw.println("The average is: " + average);


    }
```

You override every time your smallest/largest variables.

```
largest = 0;        // 0, because when you compare with numbers between 0-1000, the new value is larger
smallest = 9999;    // 0, would be wrong here as it would be abvious the smallest number
total = 0;
amount=0;
// loop through the lines of the file, each Next elements represents one number.
// Use this loop to calc the result values, not to print out on every new number
while (infile.hasNext()){
        num = infile.nextInt();

        // override the largest variable with the new largest number
        if (num > largest){
            largest = num;
        }
        // override the smallest variable with the new smallest number
        if (num < smallest){
            smallest = num;
        }
        // needed to calc the average
        total += num;
        amount++; 
    }
average = (total / amount);

System.out.println("The largest is: " + largest);
prw.println("The largest is: " + largest);
System.out.println("The smallest is: " + smallest);
prw.println("The smallest is: " + smallest);
System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
prw.println("The average is: " + average);
```